# How to write a program that transfers points of interest between a GPS device and a file on a PC?

Tags: gps

How can I write a program that transfers points of interest between a GPS device and a file on a PC?

Specifically, I'd like to know if all GPS devices have the same output format?  If not, what are the different kinds of formats?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are many, many standards for outputting this kind of data from GPS.

NMEA is the standard for most GPS data, but it is not (typically) used for bi-directional communication and transferring of waypoints.